# Optimal way to send data across an unknown network

Tags: graphs, distributed-systems

The problem goes as follows:

Given a graph G with a set of Vertices V, each having some capacity u, and edges between them E (not fully-connected) associated with some cost c (cost to send a unit of traffic across), some nodes want to send data of some size D to someo ther node (which they may not be connected to) with the smallest cost. Each node knows the cost at each iteration to reach each other node. When a node forwards a piece of data, it decreases its capacity by 1. When that value becomes 0, the node can no longer forward any more data. Obviously if a node disconnects, this changes the cost to reach any other node, so nodes update that immediately. Nodes only have local information (the cost on the edges they are connected to, the cost of their neighbours to the destination node, and their neighbours' capacities). Given this, send data of size D in minimum possible cost.

Obviously sending each time to the fastest node available is suboptimal in many case. Consider the very simple example of:

| A header | N1 | N2 | N3 | N4 | N5 | N6 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| N1 | 0 | 1 | 2 | -1 | -1 | -1 |
| N2 | 1 | 0 | -1 | 1 | 2 | -1 |
| N3 | 2 | -1 | 0 | 1 | 1000 | -1 |
| N4 | -1 | 1 | 1 | 0 | -1 | 1 |
| N5 | -1 | 2 | 1000 | -1 | 0 | 1 |
| N6 | -1 | -1 | -1 | 1 | 1 | 0 |

Each node has a capacity of 1, with N1 trying to send to N6. If N1 greedily picks fastest path each time, then it will send first to N2 (as at time 0 it has cost to N6 of 3) (with total path cost of 3 N1->N2->N4->N6)  and then to N3 (with total path cost of 1003 N1->N3->N5->N6). The optimal assignment is paths N1->N2->N5->N6 and N1->N3->N4->N6, giving total cost of 8.

The problem is that N1 doesn't have the knowledge about N3->N5 vs N3->N4 nor does N2 have that knowledge.

My question is whether there exists an algorithm which can solve this problem optimally. As in just by passing messages between peers agree on optimal sending of for example at the same time from N1 to N6 and from N3 to N5 (both of size 1)?